# BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toArray()'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working along with @Jeffrey_way series of Laracasts
[Many to Many Relations (With Tags)](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/21)

Below is the code I have written in CMD using Laravel Tinker:

[image]

After executing the last line of code (`$article->tags()->toArray();`

Although everything seems to be OK with my code but still I get following error:

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toArray()'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to actually "get" relational data, you don't put parenthesis arount `tags`. This will work just fine:

```
$article->tags->toArray();
```

You put parenthesis when you need to "query" to that collection (Ex. sync, save, attach).

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Thank you Yigit I was adding parentheses from my own dumb head :p although it wasn't in the training video

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding `get()`

For example:

```
$article->tags()->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$article->tags()->all()->toArray();
```

Underlying the `tags()` is probably a `Query\Builder` object which represents a query that has not yet run.  Instead you need a Collection object which is a query that has run, on which to call `toArray()`.  `->all()` is one such call that converts a query builder into a collection by actually running the query.

Comment: now I get this error: `BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()'`

Comment: Depending on your version of Laravel, all() may return either a collection or an array. If it returns an array then you don't need the ->toArray() bit at all.